# How to download 3rd party rpm packages with all the dependencies for offline installation?

Tags: centos, rhel, yum, rpm

I want to download all the .rpm files for the below packages with all its dependencies. The problem is yum cannot find any of them nor its dependencies.
I want all these .rpm files for offline installation in another secluded redhat server.

- protobuf-devel
- leveldb-devel
- hdf5-devel
- gflags-devel
- glog-devel
- lmdb-devel

I am using yumdownloader and I got the below error for the above packages

```
No package package-name available.                     
Error: Nothing to do
```

I used the command below

```
yumdownloader --resolve snappy-devel
```

for other packages like

- snappy-devel
- opencv-devel
- boost-devel
- atlas-devel

for which it worked perfectly and downloaded all the packages and the required dependencies *.rpm

Please tell me how to do the same for the other packages mentioned in the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that `yumdownloader` cannot find any package with that name.

Either those packages have different names (try searching yourself using `yum search protobuf` for example); either you need to add new repositories that do contain those packages.

Comment: Hi, those packages are available in https://rpmfind.net/ but I dont know. what is the repositories url for that website is. And I dont know how to add the same in a red hat linux?

Comment: you can use yum-repo-manager to add a repo